# How to export JSON data that has dynamic key value pairs with no specific properties into an excel file using Angular 7 and PrimeNg?

Tags: angular7, primeng

I have a table that contains a collection of files.
My use case is that when a user clicks on a row in that table, an event will be fired that will make a call to the service and get the JSON data. the JSON data is going to change whenever user clicks on a different row in a table. So I am not going to have specific properties or let's say keys (in key value pair). I am just gonna get JSON data in the form of a 2D string array. 
Now my task is to grab this data and export it into excel document.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to this problem and I am posting it here. Here are the links I had referred to in order to make this work.
   https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-export-xlsx
   https://medium.com/@madhavmahesh/exporting-an-excel-file-in-angular-927756ac9857

The first thing to do is

```
npm install xlsx
```

Then create a service -->

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as FileSaver from 'file-saver';
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';

const EXCEL_TYPE =
    'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';
const EXCEL_EXTENSION = '.xlsx';

@Injectable()
export class ExcelService {
    constructor() {}

    public exportAsExcelFile(json: any[], excelFileName: string): void {
        const worksheet: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(json);
        console.log('worksheet', worksheet);
        const workbook: XLSX.WorkBook = { Sheets: { data: worksheet }, SheetNames: ['data'] };
        const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });
        // const excelBuffer: any = XLSX.write(workbook, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'buffer' });
        this.saveAsExcelFile(excelBuffer, excelFileName);
    }

    private saveAsExcelFile(buffer: any, fileName: string): void {
        const data: Blob = new Blob([buffer], {
            type: EXCEL_TYPE
        });
        FileSaver.saveAs(data, fileName + '_export_' + new Date().getTime() + EXCEL_EXTENSION);
    }
}
```

Import this service in your main component (app.module.ts or whatever your component is). Make sure you add that service in the 'providers' array.

Then in your TS file, add this function -->

```
  exportAsXLSX(): void {

        this.someService.getFileData(this.clientFile).subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                if (res.data) {
                    this.fileData = res.data;
                }
            },
            err => {
                let someMsg = 'Error exporting file';
                if (err.status === 409) {
                    someMsg =
                        err.error.error.errorMessage.length > 0
                            ? err.error.error.errorMessage
                            : someMsg;
                }
                this.toastService.error(someMsg);
            }
        );
        this.excelService.exportAsExcelFile(this.fileData, 'sample');
    }
```

Here, this.fileData is an array of type any, defined as fileData: any [] in my component. It's totally up to you how to get data in this array. The main thing is to pass it to the function that will convert this to excel.
Now that you have your service written and your component has a function for it, it's time to wire this up to the HTML file.

```
                 <div class="ui-helper-clearfix">
                        <button
                            type="button"
                            pButton
                            icon="fa fa-file-excel-o"
                            iconPos="left"
                            label="Export To Excel"
                            (click)="exportAsXLSX()"
                            style="float:left"
                        ></button>
                    </div>
```

On click of the button, you will be able to get data in an excel document.